# JPA - ManyToMany Cascading behavior

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have a simple  manyToMany relationship between **Students** and **Classes**.

**Tables:**

- student
- student_classe (JOIN TABLE)
- classe

Querying data is working flawless, but saving is not getting the relation between student and classes saved into student_classe table, or, when I use **CASCADE = ALL** in the Student OneToMany relation, it throws an exception:

```
(org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "classe_pkey"):
```

I thought using CascadeType.DETACH in the ManyToOnes relationships in the JOIN TABLE would avoid that to happen. What Am I missing here?

```
@Table(name = "student")
@Entity
class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    private Set<StudentClasse> studentClasses;

   // ...
}

@Embeddable
public class StudentClasseId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8635992607670843018L;

    @Column(name = "student_id", nullable = false)
    private Long studentId;

    @Column(name = "classe_id", nullable = false)
    private Long classeId;

   // ...
}

@Table(name = "student_classe")
@Entity
class StudentClasse {

    @EmbeddedId
    private StudentClasseId id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @MapsId("studentId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")        
    private Student student;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @MapsId("classeId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "classe_id")        
    private Classe classe;
    
    // ...
}

@Table(name = "classe")
@Entity
class Classe {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "classe")
    private Set<StudentClasse> studentClasses;

   // ...
}
```

Comment: You could compare your mappings with mappings from [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/).

Answer (score 0):

In such scenarios you should avoid using cascade all, cascase persist and cascade remove in ManyToMany associations, when you create an association between new student and available classe and try to save it, hibernate will try to save the assigned classe as new entry since its not managed (detached) and you get the duplicate key value violates unique constraint error. You should update only the association.